# Where does U for voltage come from?

Tags: theory, ohms-law

I believe in Europe the letter U is commonly used for voltage in (eg.) Ohm's law \$U = I × R \$. I think I understand where the letter V came from, commonly used in North America. But what's the story with U?

Comment: Sloppily drawn V?

Comment: In Physics, U is used for potential energy, so that's....something.

Comment: I've tracked it down to ISO 31, IEC 60027, and ISO/IEC 80000, but I don't have thousands of dollars to spend on something that may or may not be useful in answering the question.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I think it was way before ISO and IEC times that the letter was introduced.

Comment: Sure, but I figured that there was a slim chance that it could point towards the origin.

Comment: Just to add further confusion: I originally learned Ohm's law as E=IR (in the US in the 1960s)

Comment: @Tut I believe I was taught E [V/m] is for electric field strength (Netherland / Europe; 1980-2000).

Comment: @jippie Yeah, it's all very confusing. We were told (in the context of Ohm's law) that E stood for "[Electromotive force](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromotive_force)". This form of Ohm's law is still in use by some.

Comment: @Tut Indeed, my electronics classes used "E" for EMF as well, and although I regard it as deprecated, I still remember `P = IE` and think, "Mmm, pie!"

Comment: Is it too late to agree with electromotive force for 'E'? ;o)

Comment: Ohm used u, but doesn't state why he chose it: http://www.deutschestextarchiv.de/book/show/ohm_galvanische_1827

Comment: My teacher told me U is used because V was already taken by velocity

Comment: I must be a lot older than you all. I first heard of Ohm's law as E=IR.

Comment: 5 upvotes for dextorb's comment? Voltage is not energy! (potential or other)

Comment: @Joris: First, he didn't say so, did he. Second, they *are* indeed almost the same: voltage is the electric potential energy *per unit charge*. So, those votes are earned.

Comment: @Sz. Come on now. Saying they're almost the same is like saying power and energy are almost the same. Their dimension is different so they must represent a completely different physical entity. (Which they do)

Comment: @Joris, Take it easy, nobody is trying to secretly undermine the laws of physics here, i think. ;) OK, let me reword: not "almost the same", but "very closely, like embarrassingly intimately related". Happy now? ;) (If we were single electrons, we would not even really understand the difference. But we,  EE.SE users, do.)

Comment: This is supposedly a derived SI unit, and most of these terms come from [André-Marie Ampère](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andr%C3%A9-Marie_Amp%C3%A8re) so I'd say it is most likely to assume it originates from French. Less likely Latin or Greek. Quite unlikely from German textbooks. According to wiki, `I` comes from _intensité de courant_ which was the term used by Ampère.

Comment: Anyway, good question, bad answers. Just speculation without canonical sources, sadly.

Comment: Don't know but PUI and URI are dead simple to remember.

Answer (score 20):

The best reason I've heard is to avoid this: -

V = 2 V (which of course is meant to say "voltage = 2 volts")

U = 2 V sounds more sensible after all we use a different symbol for current (I) and also amps. Voltage is a bit on its own - we wouldn't say "amps = 2 amps" or "current = 2 currents".

It seems to me this is the sensible reason for choosing U over V but having said that I never use "U"! Maybe I should?

Comment: Kind of the same reason why we use `j` instead of `i` for imaginary numbers (\$\sqrt{-1}\$).

Comment: Note that in any properly typeset document it should be well enough distinguishable: _V_ = 2 V, or _I_ = 3 A.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I think the point is that for V to equal 2 V, V must equal zero i.e. it is an algebraic nonsence that also doesn't look good for the uninitiated!!

Comment: As you know, many lazy typists have taken to using "u" to avoid typing two additional letters to write "you" - so maybe using it for voltages would be confusing to them. On that note, please go right ahead!

Comment: Also, the U in Physics was traditionally used for "Potential Energy", which is exactly what "voltage" is.

Comment: @jose.angel.jimenez No, voltage is Potential Energy Per Unit Charge, not just Potential Energy.

Comment: I have never used U for voltage; seems rather stupid to me.

Answer (score 13):

I found another explanation [here](http://boards.straightdope.com/sdmb/archive/index.php/t-338522.html):

> Germans took freedoms and started calling voltage "U", probably since that letter was largely unused and so couldn't be confused with anything else. They also came up with etymology: U is for *Unterschied*, which is German and means "difference"; very fitting since voltage is obviously the same as potential difference.

So it's U for Unterschied (which means "difference")

Comment: Interesting find, although for German I would expect `differenz` to be used.

Comment: Over the decades I have heard lots of explanations for U, but never that one. I find U for *urgere* the most plausible, since back in the days, people did love to use latin.

Answer (score 7):

Doesn't answer where **U** comes from but [here](http://www.linkedin.com/groups/voltage-symbol-u-v-In-2091456.S.257065070) is a similar discussion:

> *Q: voltage symbol u or v? In German Physics books: I = U/R means I[A] = U[V]/R[Ohm] It seems to be that in English you would write: I[A] = V[V]/R[Ohm] Right or wrong?*

I liked these three comments

> <sub>Radoslaw J.
>
>     PhD., Eng.; R&D Magnetic and Power Electronic Engineer, Project Leader at ABB PL Corporate Research Center</sub>
>
> Both of voltage description "U" and "V" are proper, however it must be mentioned that in European notation "U" describes voltage source while "V" describes rather voltage potential. It means that U = V1 - V1 (voltage is a difference between voltage potentials). I agree that in IEEE and American standards voltage is described by "V" letter.
>   Very similar situation is with other electric symbols also (e.g. resistors, capacitors, current sources, etc.), where European and American standards are different.

> <sub>Dejan K.
>
>   Supervisory Board Member at JP Energetika Maribor d.o.o.</sub>
>
> Based on experience with writing articles I can conclude the following:
>   For European scientific space U and I are signs for average value of voltage and current respectively and u, i are signs for instantaneous values of voltage and current. U is more appropriate to use not to mix the parameter U with its value in V (volts).

> Per L.
>
> I don't know if US or IEEE standards, or any other standards for that sake, are more rightful than other regional standards. However, I learned to use U for voltage at school and personally I think U = 5 V makes more sense than V = 5 V, but I'm flexible

Comment: So from IEEE, should we use V instead of U, even if U seems a bit better? Should we use always V since it's in standards?

Answer (score 6):

Voltage is a difference.

In German "difference" is "**Unterschied**".

The chain of thought is that there is a difference in number of free electrons between two places.

Electrons that can move are free to move.
If there are many such free electrons we call that a "charge".

Analogy: Imagine a train with two carriages full of people, say 40 + 40. If a school class (20 pupils) leaves one of the cars, people will move to use empty space and spread evenly in the train.

So voltage tells us the difference in number of electrons that can move and spread evenly between two places.

Since electricity goes back to Georg Ohm in Germany the explanation fits.
Sadly, it is too late to ask late Mr. Ohm if it is true or not.

But I have noticed that my students find it helpful.

I my teaching I use E for “voltage rise” i.e. source of electrons that are free to move (battery, capacitor) and U for “voltage drops” (resistors).

This gives an advantage in analyzing circuitry as now I can compare electrical circuits to things my students are already familiar with like water circulating in a fountain or even income and payments.

Comment: In math, you would say "differenz."  "Unterschied" is more when discussing things or people.

Answer (score 5):

Some German textbooks claim that the origin of the symbol **U** is unknown. One possible explanation is that it comes from the Latin word *urgere* which [can mean](http://www.latin-dictionary.net/search/latin/urgere)

1. press/squeeze/bear hard/down
2. push/shove/thrust
3. tread/traverse continually

Answer (score 1):

Using V for Voltage would be problematic when working with both units and dimensions. We have a dimension of "length (s,d or l)" with a unit "meter [m]", but having a dimension of "voltage (V)" with a unit of "voltage [V]" would not be fun to work with.

Comment: Why is it not fun?

Answer (score -3):

We have to use U because V was already taken. 
V stands for Volume and to avoid confusion in calculations we use U.

Simple as that.

Comment: Do you have a source to back this up. Seems kind of illogical to me since volume is not an electrical unit, but a mechanical one. There's no situation in which volume will be in an equation with voltage.